# Parsing the JSON response for field values

Tags: json

How can I parse my JSON response to extract a single or multiple values?

```
{
"APIKey": "98cab291-cc3a-ffc5-fc13-55ca591b42b7", 
"ValidUntil": "/Date(1472126955624)/"
}
```

I need to extract just the APIKey from the response. Is this possible ?

Comment: have you tried anything ? And why is this even a question?

Comment: Yes I tried the print command but that only provides the ability to output the entire response body. I can obviously pipe it through JQ, which works fine but that involves using another utility.

Comment: can you show code of what you have tried?

Comment: I tried `http --print=b.APIKEY --verify=no -j POST https://192.168.13.235/sdk/authorize/ Username=admin Password=xxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in this case:

jq command to get what you are asking for would be

```
<request> | jq '. APIKey'
```